# Как сверстать буквы 2 цветов?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать буквы 2 цветов серый и желтый (микрозелень) ?

Я думал что все кроме горшка надо делать на css

Comment: Зачем? Это же явная картинка. Я бы на svg делал если уж очень хочется

Comment: @Alexey Ten Здравствуйте я думал это надо делать css ведь есть правило  что можно сделать средствами css то надо делать css

Comment: @Leks Тот горшочек с цветами скорее всего тоже можно сделать через CSS)) С какого-то момента легче за 30 секунд нарисовать, чем долго верстать)

Comment: @Leks ну давайте ещё каждую фотографию делать из миллионов div'ов размерами 1x1 пиксель, раскрашивая их через css? Не нужно доводить до абсурда; если нет особенных требований к адаптивности или иной гибкости — может оказаться проще, надёжнее и производительнее сделать обычной картинкой

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может быть так?

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 0%, gray 11%, wheat 11.1%, wheat 89%, gray 89.1%, gray 100%);
```

```css
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 0%, gray 11%, wheat 11.1%, wheat 89%, gray 89.1%, gray 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 20vw;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Hello</div>
```